# How to not share Goals in a shared Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

My Google calendar is shared with my wife; she can see all event details in my calendar. As a New Year's resolution, I started to use Goals (Android suggested this). Now my wife is totally freaking out because on her phone, the Calendar app is completely filled with her events, my events, and my goals. She does not want to see my goals.

My question is: how can I keep using Goals in a shared Calendar, without the Goals being shared? All other normal events still need to be shared.

I tried setting the events as private, but because of the sharing level, she can still see the Goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, because I found a working solution through trial and error.

First, you need to know that Goals are always added to your first calendar. You can add many calendars to your Google Calendar account, but when you add a goal, you cannot choose to which calendar the goal should be added. I tried adding a separate "Goals" calendar, but I could not add any goals to it.

So I did it the other way around.

- On PC, go to the Google Calendar website (it's easier to do it on PC than on Android. Trust me. I tried.)
- In My Calendars on the left, click on the little arrow next to your primary calendar and choose Calendar settings.
- Rename your primary calendar to "Goals"
- Unshare your primary calendar
- Again in My Calendars, create a new Calendar
- Name the new calendar "Shared Calendar"
- Share the new calendar with whoever you had originally shared your primary calendar

This is just the setup. Now comes the fun/boring part:

- For *every* current event in your calendar, edit the event and change the calendar from "Goals" to "Shared".
- Don't bother doing this with past events, you'll get bored soon enough.
- From now on, every time you add a new event, you'll have to remember to add it to your "Shared" calendar.

End result:

- Android Goals are in the "Goals" calendar and aren't shared.
- Events are in the "Shared" calendar and are shared.